# Issue formatting the initialization of a variable in a service

Tags: java, android, variables, bundle, extras

Getting an error on the line:

```
String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", mdn));
```

Stating: The local variable mdn may not have been initialized

The problem is if I Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); just above that line I end up getting a "duplicate local variable extras" error - and if I remove the first instance of Bundle Extras - I get more of these same errors. I simply need a bit of help formatting this so it will execute without any errors.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;



    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        // super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);





        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {






                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountService.class);

                StartActivity(i);  



                Intent MDN = new Intent(this, MDNByteswapService.class);

                StartActivity(MDN);  


                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";

                    String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", mdn));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + mdn + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));

                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");
                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();
                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        // set status to enabled

                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                }   } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;0")) {
                    // set status to disabled
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("status", "0");
                    editor.commit();
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                }



        return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);
                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    //

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

SOURCE AFTER FIRST EDIT:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        // super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountService.class);

                    StartActivity(i);

                    Intent MDN = new Intent(this, MDNByteswapService.class);

                    StartActivity(MDN);

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";

                    String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn",
                            "some_default_value_here"));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + mdn + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));

                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");
                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();
                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        // set status to enabled

                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                }
            } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0")) {
                // set status to disabled
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("status", "0");
                editor.commit();
                stopSelf();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                // character
            }

            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);
                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    //

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Service which saves the MDN in SharedPreferences:

```
public class DataCountUtilities extends Service {

    // swap the content of a string by switching place
    // each pair of consecutive characters
    // If string length is odd last character is left in place
    public String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";
        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

            // Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);
            // i.putExtra("key", mdn);
            // tartActivity(i);

            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("mdn", mdn);
            editor.commit();

        }

        return String.valueOf(data);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    // private void startActivity(Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized mdn yet.  You can't create something and use that something in its creation.  Example:

```
int x = 1+x;//how does the compiler know what x is?
```

You can't create use x in the initialization of int x because it doesn't exist.  Remember that Java is case sensitive.  You could have meant:

```
String mdn = settings.getString("mdn", "default_string");
```

Take a look at the API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare and use a variable in a single line like that:

```
String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", mdn));
```

The second parameter in [getString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the default value - in case there is no entry with "mdn" key, that is the value you will receive from getString.

So you should probably replace that line with:

```
String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", "some_default_value_here"));
```

or declare and initialize mdn before:

```
String mdn = "some_default_value";
mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", mdn));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you where you mention "some_default_value_here"

I'm saving it in another service using:

SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
     .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
   Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putString("mdn", mdn);
   editor.commit();


and when I try to retrieve it using your method with the some_default_value_here swapped out to match - it isn't working:

String mdn = (settings.getString("mdn", mdn));

Comment: `getString` needs to return something. A benefit it brings is that it can return a default value if no value is found for that key. If you're saying that you are ALWAYS writing some value for that key before you'll read it, then you can pass null (or any String value) since you will get another value instead. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes - but I'm always saving the MDN - it's the phone number - it should never be null 


P.S.

I'm still not getting the byteswapped MDN from my 2nd service for some reason - it just shows up in the SMS as "some_default_value_here" where I should have a byteswapped MDN instead

Comment: That means you're not saving the mdn. Take a second look at your code and at getString method documentation.